# Multiplying big numbers

Tags: c++, pow, bigint

The problem is to multiply big numbers.

I am using a base of 10^9, and get problems when the numbers get to
tenth of that.  In the example below, I use a much smaller base for
simplicity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<long long> largen;

const int base = 1000;

largen  multiply(largen a, largen b) {
    largen c(a.size() + b.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i<a.size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0, carry = 0; j < (int)b.size() || carry; ++j) {
            long long cur = c[i + j] + a[i] * 1ll * (j < (int)b.size() ? b[j] : 0) + carry;
            carry = (long long)(cur / base);
            c[i + j] = (long long)(cur % base);
        }
    while (c.size() > 1 && c.back() == 0)
        c.pop_back();
    return c;
}

int main() {
    largen a = {100};
    largen result = multiply(a, a);
    for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << result[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected answer "10000", actual answer "100"

Comment: Check [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Comment: it is easier to use already implemented solution like this bigint library https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Comment: Rather than multiply by `1LL`, I'd static cast to long long.  Rather than continuing the inner loop if there is a carry, I'd declare `carry` outside the inner loop, and check it for non-zero afterwardss.  That may save you a comparison in the loop.  Of course, none of that explains why the answer is *wrong*.

Comment: Set the base to 100 (because you can do those calculations in your head), and step through it in a debugger.

Comment: And can we have a [mcve] please

Comment: @Pooya - I suspect this is a class exercise, in which case using an already implemented solution doesn't really fit the requirements.  (For real projects of course, you'd use pretested libraries.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::numeric_limits<long>::max` has to be >1E9, and `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max` has to be greater than 1E18 (doesn't it?), so I don't see a problem.  (I may be being thick of course.)

Comment: Why don't you just use an existing bignum library like - - for example - GMP: https://gmplib.org/ ?

Comment: [programm](http://cpp.sh/97lxb)
Example 
input:
10203756485819806252197658031528043601970

2
correct output:

104116646421909761950282879573175588809976767764774752111453905887721451787880900

Comment: I can't use existing library, because it's a task and I am the first course student.

Comment: @MartinBonner [programm](http://cpp.sh/97lxb)

Comment: a) That program is nothing like "Minimal".  b) We want it edited into the question - not an external link that will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is why we demand a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example.  Once we have that, we can see that the problem is *nothing* to do with the multiplication.  In fact the problem is in the lines:

```
    for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << result[i];
    }
```

If you change that to:

```
    for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << result[i] << '#'
    }
```

The output changes from the (incorrect) "100", to a much more interesting "10#0#".  The second digit is being displayed as a single digit zero, rather than three zeros.  Use `setw` and padding to make sure that all but the first digit are zero filled.